# como incluir una variable dentro de una consulta sql (Select * from @variable) en c#

Tags: c#, sql

```
string prueba1 = usuarios;
conexion.Open();
            string str = "SELECT * FROM @nombre";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conexion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre",prueba1);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader sd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            data.Load(sd);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            sd.Close();
            conexion.Close();
```

intente hacerlo con: + QUOTENAME(@tablename)
intente hacerlo con: '"+prueba1+"'

ninguna dio resultados

Sucede que previamente tengo una tabla principal a la cual quiero realizarle copias y renombrarlas con el nombre de un nuevo usuario registrado, el cual se almacenara en "prueba1", de esta forma cada vez que se registre un nuevo usuario obtendrá una copia de la tabla independiente sin dañar la principal

Comment: será que `prueba1` deberia ser `string prueba1 = "usuarios"` ?

Comment: No se puede. Es una mala práctica porque cada tabla debe de tener una estructura distinta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, lo único que debes hacer es concatenar la variable al string:

```
 string text = "sql" + variable + ""
```

Comment: tu ayuda a resuelto este problema.

Comment: Esperaba una advertencia por la inyección SQL, y una recomendación a utilizar *prepared statements*... pero no fue el caso...